# Can't create/write to file (Errcode: 30)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux, centos, server

I recently had an error on my mysql database and against better judgement (I'm not a server guy at all) I tried to resolve it through googling and changing server stuff...

So first off, mysql was showing this error "Can't create/write to file  (Errcode: 30)"

I think I followed these answers which ended up causing more problems:
[MySQL: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_3c6_0.MYI' (Errcode: 2) - What does it even mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997012/mysql-cant-create-write-to-file-tmp-sql-3c6-0-myi-errcode-2-what-does)
http://nixcraft.com/showthread.php/14260-ERROR-1-(HY000)-Can-t-create-write-to-file-tmp-sql_9f3_0-MYI-(Errcode-13)

Only looking back, I see that these googled answers have different error codes, not "30"

Here is the log of the actions I did, causing the server to fail even more at the end (mysqld won't even restart up now)

```
[root@xxx ~]# /usr/sbin/lsof /tmp
[root@xxx ~]# /bin/umount -l /tmp
umount: /tmp: not mounted
[root@xxx ~]# /bin/umount -l /var/tmp
umount: /var/tmp: not mounted
[root@xxx ~]#  cat /etc/my.cnf | grep tmpdir
[root@xxx ~]#
[root@xxx ~]# cat /etc/my.cnf | grep tmpdir
[root@xxx ~]# chown root:root /tmp
chown: changing ownership of `/tmp': Read-only file system
[root@xxx ~]# chmod 1777 /tmp
chmod: changing permissions of `/tmp': Read-only file system
[root@xxx ~]# /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
rm: cannot remove `/var/lock/subsys/mysqld': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock': Read-only file system
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
[root@xxx ~]# chmod 777 /var/lock/subsys/mysqld
chmod: changing permissions of `/var/lock/subsys/mysqld': Read-only file system
[root@xxx ~]# chmod 777 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
chmod: changing permissions of `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock': Read-only file system
[root@xxx ~]# /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
[root@xxx ~]# /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
[root@xxx ~]#
```

From the links listed above, you'll see that I tried following things such as

```
"check mysql config : my.cnf
cat /etc/my.cnf | grep tmpdir
I can't see anything in my my.cnf
add tmpdir=/tmp to my.cnf under [mysqld]
restart web/app and mysql server
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart"
" chown root:root /tmp
  chmod 1777 /tmp
  /etc/init.d/mysqld restart"
```

But yeah, I haven't touched it since because I think I would just be messing it up even more.

Server running is CentOS 6.5 64bit LAMP

Let me know if anyone could shed some insight or if I should provide anymore information. Thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: It appears like your filesystem is mounted as 'read only'. You can verify this by running `mount` (a read only command, it will not change anything). If 'ro' is mentioned in any of the relevant mounts (like "/" or "/var"), it means the filesystem cannot be written to. If that is the case, it is possible there is a problem with the filesystem or the disk itself, and Linux has marked it as read only to protect it against further problems. Run `dmesg | less` (another read only command) to check for system log messages regarding disk or filesystem problems.